# Evaluation of "concentration of measure function" at zero.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space equipped with a probability measure $\mu$ (defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the topology induced by the metric $d$). We define the *concentration function* of the triple $X,d$ and $\mu$ as follows:

$\alpha_{(X,d,\mu)}(r)=\sup\{1-\mu(A_r):A\subset X\text{ is measurable and }\mu(A)\geq 1/2\}$, $r\geq0$,

where we define $A_r=\{x\in X:d(x,A)<r\}$ (EDIT: I adopt the convention $A_0=A$).

I am interested in the value of the following (sparing you the elementary details that leads to the equality below):

$\alpha_{(X,d,\mu)}(0)=\sup\{\mu(B):B\subset X\text{ is measurable and }\mu(B)\leq 1/2\}$

If there exists a measurable set $A\subset X$ such that $\mu(A)=1/2$,
then it clearly is the case that $\alpha_{(X,d,\mu)}(0)=1/2$.
If there is no set with measure $1/2$, then the situation is not so clear.
I can easily find examples where there is no set of measure $1/2$ and $\alpha_{(X,d,\mu)}(0)$ is not $1/2$ (Dirac probability measure comes to mind), but I am unable to either prove (by finding an example ideally) or disprove that there exists a probability measure on some metric space such that no set has a measure of $1/2$ but $\alpha_{(X,d,\mu)}(0)=1/2$.

Comment: I would like to check something about the question: as you state it the second half of the question doesn't involve $r$-neighbourhoods at all, since we take $A_0$ in the definition of $\alpha(0)$ to be just $A$. If by $A_0$ you meant $\bigcap_{r \rightarrow 0} A_r$, the question would be different and the equality $\alpha(0) = \sup\{\mu(B)\ldots$ might not hold. Did you definitely mean it the way that you wrote it?

Comment: Now that you mention it I realize that it is not at all clear what $A_0$ should be. It is tempting to use the convention $A_0=A$, but then again we might as well say it's the empty set, since $\{x\in X:d(x,A)<0\}=\varnothing$. The intersection is also a good candidate. So to clarify: I will adopt the convention $A_0=A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the image of any finite measure is closed (see [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1948-54-04/S0002-9904-1948-09020-6/S0002-9904-1948-09020-6.pdf)), which implies that $1/2$ (or any other constant $\alpha\in[0,1]$ for that matter) cannot be a limit point of the image of $\mu$ without being itself in the image of $\mu$.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  You can accept your own answer, and I'd invite you to do so!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, I think that the question is equivalent to saying the following:

Is it possible to have a sequence of sets whose measure tends upwards to $\frac{1}{2}$, without there being a set who measure is $\frac{1}{2}$?

Clearly, if the sets are nested, this is not possible, not just in a Borel $\sigma$ algebra generated by a metric, but in any measure space.

If we don't have a probability measure, we can take a sequence of disconnected points whose measure tends upwards to $\frac{1}{2}$. If they all have measure above $\frac{1}{4}$, then there could be no set which has measure exactly $\frac{1}{2}$.

Now, maybe you can consider a similar situation, and try and show that a sequence of disconnected points whose total measure is 1, where there are finite subsets whose measure tends upwards towards $\frac{1}{2}$, must have a subset of measure $\frac{1}{2}$.

This is a fact about sums of a sequence of real numbers, rather than about measure theory. I didn't think it through quite yet, so it might be trivial or non-trivial (or false).

But if you can show that there must be a set of measure $\frac{1}{2}$ for the sequence of disconnected points, this might imply the general case. Post back if you manage to carry any of the above out, otherwise I will let you know anything further I think of.

Comment: I haven't been able to work out any of your proposed solutions yet, but as I was working on it I observed something which might be useful:
If the sequence of sets $\{A_n\}$ is such that $\mu(A_n)\to 1/2$ and pairwise disjoint, then $\mu$ cannot be a probability measure. Indeed, if we fix $k\in(0,1/2)$, then there must be countably many $A_i$ such that $\mu(A_i)\in(1/2-k,1/2+k)$. Let $\{A_{i_n}\}_{n}$ be all of them. Since they are pairwise disjoint, we obtain:
$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n}A_{i_n}\right)=\sum_{n}\mu(A_{i_n})\geq\sum_{n}(1/2-k)=\infty$.

Comment: Right. This is roughly what I proposed when I said 'If we don't have a probability measure...' This construction does not work with a probability measure. So the solution, if one exists, would have to involve countable many sets of measure roughly one half, which each overlap with many others, but yet there isn't a nested sequence whose measure tends to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible now, but still need to figure out an argument.